# Textbox values based on another textbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

[image]

**What I want**: I have attached the image of a website where people can select ingredients from a list of ingredients and then here they can add the weight of particular ingredients.

Each ingredient has fat, solids etc which is already defined per gram in database and I want to update the values in real time when user changes the weight of that ingredient.

By default, the weight of all ingredient here is 1 gram and then default values of fat,sweetness etc for 1 gram , if user makes it 10 gram then fat, sweetness etc will be multiplied by the default value with 10. and also decrease when user decreases the weight.

I want the weight of water to be sum of weight of all the ingredients - 1000. How can I do that?

I am adding the code here:

HTML

```
   <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Weight" class='smalltextbo onlynumbers' id="w<?=$thedetails_array['sno']?>" onkeyup="return updatevalues(this);" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);"; value='1'/></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name='fat' value="<?=$thedetails_array['fat']?>" id="fat<?=$thedetails_array['sno']?>" readonly></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name='sweet' value="<?=$thedetails_array['sweet']?>" id="sweet<?=$thedetails_array['sno']?>" readonly></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name='solid1' value="<?=$thedetails_array['solid1']?>" id="solid<?=$thedetails_array['sno']?>" readonly></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
function updatevalues(vale){
            var mainid=$(vale).attr("id");
            var onlyidis=mainid.substr(1);
            var mainval=$('#w'+onlyidis).val();

            var varfatval=$('#fat'+onlyidis).val();
            $('#fat'+onlyidis).val(varfatval*mainval);

            var varfatval=$('#sweet'+onlyidis).val();
            $('#sweet'+onlyidis).val(varfatval*mainval);


}
```

I have a data of real solids, fat and sweet in 1 gram of milk then update it with the real weight of milk here.

Comment: Replace `onkeyup="return updatevalues(this);"` with `onkeyup="updatevalues(this);"`

Comment: its not gona change anything , what i need is to update the values everytime i change weight, right now there is something wrong with function i think. also i think i may need different approach for this ??